# Concrete representation of the annihilating algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $\mathfrak{M} = A^{\prime\prime}$, where $A$ is a concretely described subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(\ell^{2}(\mathbb{N}))$. In some instances, it is possible to provide a concrete description of the Operators in $A''$. Is the same possible for $A^{\prime}$?

Consider, *e. g.* $G$ a fixed group, and view $L(G)$ as acting on $\mathcal{B}(\ell^{2}(G))$. Can the operators in $L(G)^{\prime}$ be more concretely described (other than simply commuting with every $L_{g}$ for $g\in G$ --- where $L_{g} : \mathbf{e}_{h} \mapsto \mathbf{e}_{gh}$ for each $g, h\in G$)?

Answer (score 1):

The case you mention is one of the very few where the commutant can be expressed explicitly.

Namely,
$
L(G)'=R(G), $ where
$R(G) $ is the von Neumann algebra of the right regular representation $R_g:e_h\mapsto e_{hg} $.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would you be able to further comment, whether $L(G)·R(G) = \mathcal{B}(\ell^{2}(G))$? (or if this at least for the SOT-closure of the Algebra generated by the two holds)

Comment: The second case you mention always holds when $M$ is a factor (which is the case for $L(G)$ when $G$ is i.c.c.): if you have $M\subset B(H)$, then $$(M\cup M')'=M'\cap M''=M'\cap M=Z(M)=\mathbb C.$$ So $(M\cup M')''=B(H).$

Comment: Ah! Of course! Thanks for the reminder.